# Woocommerce: Using WC_AJAX class

Tags: wordpress, oop, woocommerce

I hope you can help.

I've upgraded Woocommerce to version 2.1.12 and I had a function woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments() which is now missing.

It looks like they've moved it to WC_AJAX class, but when I access it with WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments(); the following error.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Using $this when not in object context in <b>/home/lmof/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
```

What can I do to access this function?

Thanks 
Mark

Comment: I assume you already know that it's adding them as an AJAX function using `add_action` ?